Linearity of Amplitudes and Lorentz Frames
I know that this question may be a bit weird, but I decided to ask. Assume I have an amplitude, say in QED, which depends on a set of four-momenta $\{p_1,\ p_2,\ p_3,\ ...,\ p_n\}$. Further assume that this amplitude is comprised of two sub-amplitudes. In other words,
$$\mathcal{M}(p_1,\ p_2,\ p_3,\ ...,\ p_n)=
\mathcal{M}_a(p_1,\ p_2,\ p_3,\ ...,\ p_n)+
\mathcal{M}_b(p_1,\ p_2,\ p_3,\ ...,\ p_n)$$
Now, my question is the following: say that I want to use a specific Lorentz frame in $\mathcal{M}_a$, i.e. $p_1=(m_1,\vec{0})$ and another Lorentz frame in $\mathcal{M}_b$, i.e. $p_2=(m_2,\vec{0})$. Am I allowed to?

No. Also, there is no way to decompose the amplitude that way. Instead, cluster decomposition principle means that amplitudes, if they are factorisable, factorise into products, not sums. And when they do factorise, the factorisation is trivial, so that the physically meaningful S matrices of interest are not factorisable, and you build the factorisable in terms of them.

@naturallyInconsistent Why is there no way to decompose an amplitude into a sum? What about multiple possibilities from photon emission from different external fermion legs?

And why am I not allowed to select two different reference frames? If both $i\mathcal{M}_a$ and $i\mathcal{M}_b$ are Lorentz invariant, I can not see why not?
